# useSelector not responding to state changes in another Route -

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I'm new to using Redux, and I'm working on a test project to better understand how to use it in conjunction with React Router. My goal is to have the state updated with user input onClick in the route `edi1` and to then use useSelector in route `edi2` to display the updated state. Currently, in route `edi1`, I can see the state updating both through useSelector and the Redux Profiler in the Dev. Tools. However, in route `edi2` it renders the initial state from the store but does not respond to any state changes. I have been getting these results by clicking Submit in `edi1` to update the state and then in a separate tab viewing route `edi2`. Even if I refresh the tab with 'edi2' the state remains as the initial state.

I've been looking through both React Router and Redux Toolkit Docs. In the React Router Docs, they recommend a "Deep Redux Integration" if you require for "Synchronize the routing data with, and accessed from, the store." (https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/deep-redux-integration). I'm not sure if that would apply to my case here, but even if it did in the past, the docs are for version 5, and I'm using the updated version of React Router 6.4.1.

I've been stuck on this issue for days, so I appreciate any guidance to help me move forward from here. Please see the CodeSandBox below to review the code. I have also included a screenshot of the Profiler from Dev tools. If further information is needed, I will be happy to provide it. Thank you for your time!

**Code:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/render-redux-state-react-router-y46wqk?file=/src/App.js

Similar Issue :

[Redux Toolkit useSelector not updating state in React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71827693/redux-toolkit-useselector-not-updating-state-in-react-component)

The solution for their issue was to update React-Redux. I have version 8.0.4 and I think that is the most updated version.

[image]

Profiler:

[image]

[image]

store.js:

```
    import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import ediReducer from './ediSlice'


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    edi: ediReducer,

  },
})
```

edislice.js:

```
    import {createSlice}  from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
   id:0, content: ["Hello World"],
}
export const ediSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'edi',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addContent: (state, action) => {
            state.content.push(action.payload); // add new content to the array
           // state.value = action.payload; // this will overwrite the array
           state.id += 1 // this will increment the id
           console.log(state.id)
        },
    }
    })

    export const {addContent} = ediSlice.actions;
    export default ediSlice.reducer;
```

SendEdi.js:

```
    import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
import {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {addContent} from "../components/ediSlice.js";

export default function SendEdi() {
const ediContent = useSelector((state) => state.edi.content);
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const editorRef = useRef();
const [entryArray, setEntryArray] = useState();
 const log = () => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
        setEntryArray(editorRef.current.getContent());
        dispatch(addContent(entryArray));
        console.log("Editor Conent:", {ediContent})
    }}
 let entryEdi = <Editor
onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
apiKey='your-api-key'
disabled = {false}
inline = {false}

init={{
 selector: "#entryEdi",
 height: 500,
 menubar: false,
 placeholder: "Whats on your mind?",
 plugins: [
   'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview',
   'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen',
   'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'code', 'help', 'wordcount'
 ],
 toolbar:  'undo redo | blocks | ' +
       'bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
       'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
       'removeformat | help',
 content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
}}
/>

return (
<div>
   {ediContent}  
   {entryEdi}
   <button onClick={log}>Submit</button>
</div>
)

}
```

RecEdi.js:

```
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";

export default function RecEdi() {
const ediContent = useSelector((state) => state.edi.content); 

    return (
        <div>
        {ediContent}
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Edi1 from "./pages/edi1";
import Edi2 from "./pages/edi2";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/Edi1" element={<Edi1 />} />
          <Route path="/Edi2" element={<Edi2 />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

edi1.js:

```
import SendEdi from "../components/SendEdi.js";
import { content } from "../components/ediSlice.js";

export default function Edi1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SendEdi />
      <h1>edi1</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

edi2.js:

```
import RecEdi from "../components/RecEdi";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Edi2() {
  // const edicontent = useSelector((state) => state.content.value)
  return (
    <div>
      <RecEdi />
      <h1>edi2</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { store } from "./components/store.js";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: This is not how SO works. We do not go somewhere else to get the contents of a question. All relevant information must be here, in the question itself, so it will remain available for future readers. Please [edit] your post to provide the code here in the form of a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the question.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't match the code in the sandbox, so it's unclear what you are actually asking for help with.

Comment: I just simplified the RecEdi component to have a minimal reproducible example. The only thing I took out was the text editor in that component. My goal is to have the state updated with user input onClick in the route edi1 and to then use useSelector in route edi2 to display the updated state so I thought the text editor for route edi2 was not necessary. The rest of the code is the same.  @DrewReese

Comment: The codesandbox still doesn't match if you are saying you've fixed anything there to match what you are asking about in your question. The problems you have in your code in the sandbox aren't called out anywhere in your question so it's unclear overall what *specific* issue you are trying to resolve. The `useSelector` hook only selects out chunks of state you specify. If you are updating state correctly it will select, i.e. pick, it. Are you having issues dispatching actions and updating the store?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to keep the code in the question to a minimum to have a minimal reproducible example but I also need to do better at balancing that with making the question clear to not cause confusion. To make things easier for everyone, the CodeSandbox and the code in the question should now be a 1:1 copy. I updated the RedEdi.js component in the CodeSandbox. I have also added the code for App.js, Index.js, Edi1.js and Edi2.js to this question. @DrewReese

Comment: As to the specific issue  that I’m trying to resolve, in the component RecEdi.js I have the line of code: const ediContent = useSelector((state) => state.edi.content); This useSelector statement is not responding to state changes from the SendEdi.js component. It never changes from the initial state of “Hello World”. @DrewReese

Comment: As far as updating the store, I have confirmed that SendEdi.js is indeed updating the store through the Redux Profiler in the dev tools. I have also confirmed this by having another useSelector statement in the same Route as SendEdi.js. I have returned the useSelector variable within a <div> so I can see first hand as the state changes and it is changing as I trigger the onClick event. @DrewReese

Comment: So useSelector doesn't work outside of Route edi1.js. It is able to access the store for the initial state but it does not respond to any state changes. 
Being new to Redux, I want to learn how I can use Redux to transfer data to components that are not closely associated within the App. In this case, the components are within two separate React Router Routes so I’m trying to have an event in one page trigger a state change within the store which then triggers a component to update on a separate page. The problem here is that the component on the separate page is not updating. @DrewReese

Comment: I see, so you are running two separate instances of your app. This means each instance of the app has its own Redux store. Changes to one won't effect anything external to the app. The other app instance won't see it. If you are wanting to "communicate" between two React apps you'll need to implement something like websockets and dispatch events to the socket to transmit data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any React Router <-> Redux integration at all - you are reading up on the wrong topic here.

You are missing one point though: Redux is an in-memory router within that one tab you have open. So if you close the tab and open it again, it will initialize from the "initial state" again. The same goes for refreshing the page, or navigating in a way that unloads the page and navigating back to the page.

Depending on what you do here, that last part might be interesting: my guess is that while you navigate from page A to page B to see your result, you are doing so in a way that unloads the whole page and reloads it again, resulting in a complete re-initialization of your Redux store.

That would mean that you are navigating wrong (not using the components or methods provided by react-router), and that's what I'd be looking for.

Of course, if everything works and you want state to stay there over a page reload, you can look into something like `redux-persist`, but for right now you should find that navigation bug first or otherwise non-redux things will break as well.